# Can't get a values according to selected values from 2 drop lists using

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have 2 drop lists, where the first drop list is getting data fro MySQL using AJAX, and here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#sale_type').change(function() {
    var formData = { 'selectedValue' : $( "#sale_type option:selected" ).val() };
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',  
       url: 'getTypeDetails.php',
       data: formData,
       success: function(data){              
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);      
      var secondDropdown = $("#sale_details");
      secondDropdown.html('');
      var init = 'إختر';
      secondDropdown.append("<option>" + init + "</option>");
      for (var prop in obj) {

         secondDropdown.append("<option>" + obj[prop] + "</option>");
        } 

       },
       error: function(errorThrown){
      alert(errorThrown);
       }

       });

     return false;
     });
   });
```

And here is the PHP code (getType...):

```
<?php
    require_once('../include/global.php');

    $init_data = $_POST['selectedValue'];
    // Connect to database
    // Use the data to get the new information
    $query = "SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE sale_type = :data";
    // MySQL
    $results = $conn->prepare($query);
    $results->bindValue(":data", $init_data);
    $exec = $results->execute();
    $res = $results->fetchAll();

    $data = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($res as $row){
         $data[$i] = $row['sale_details'];
         $i++;

    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Now, data are displayed normally inside the second drop list using the selected value in the first one, and here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#sale_type_2').change(function() {
    var formData = { 'selectedValue2' : $( "#sale_type_2 option:selected" ).val() };
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',  
       url: 'getTypeDetails_2.php',
       data: formData,
       success: function(data){              
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);      
      var secondDropdown = $("#sale_details_2");
      secondDropdown.html('');
      var init = 'إختر';
      secondDropdown.append("<option>" + init + "</option>");
      for (var prop in obj) {

         secondDropdown.append("<option>" + obj[prop] + "</option>");
        } 

       },
       error: function(errorThrown){
      alert(errorThrown);
       }

       });

     return false;
     });
   });
```

Now, I want to take the 2 selected values from those 2 drop list and display a value into a text box, so I've tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#sale_details_2').change(function() {
    var formData = { 'selectedValue' : $( "#sale_type_2 option:selected" ).val(),
    'selectedValue2' : $( "#sale_details_2 option:selected" ).val() };
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',  
       url: 'getTypeDetails_3.php',
       data: formData,
       success: function(data){              
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);      
      var secondDropdown = $("#price_2");
      secondDropdown.html('');
      for (var prop in obj) {

         secondDropdown.text(obj[prop]);
        } 

       },
       error: function(errorThrown){
      alert(errorThrown);
       }

       });

     return false;
     });
   });
```

And here is the php code:

```
<?php
    require_once('../include/global.php');

    $init_data = $_POST['selectedValue2'];
    $init_data2 = $_POST['selectedValue3'];
    // Connect to database
    // Use the data to get the new information
    $query = "SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE sale_type = :data AND sale_details = :data2";
    // MySQL
    $results = $conn->prepare($query);
    $results->bindValue(":data", $init_data);
    $results->bindValue(":data2", $init_data2);
    $exec = $results->execute();
    $res = $results->fetchAll();

    $data = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($res as $row){
         $data[$i] = $row['price'];
         $i++;

    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

But it didn't get any results and I have the following console error:

> Object {selectedValue: "BMW", selectedValue2: "despirator"}
>
> VM227:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Any help is appreciated

**EDIT**
After correcting some lines into:

```
var formData = { 'selectedValue' : $( "#sale_type_2 option:selected" ).val(),
    'selectedValue2' : $( "#sale_details_2 option:selected" ).val() };
```

And:

```
   $init_data = $_POST['selectedValue'];
    $init_data2 = $_POST['selectedValue2'];
```

I've got the same error, and here is an image for it:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the formData you are sending the values `selectedValue` & `selectedValue2` but in php you try to get `selectedValue2` & `selectedValue3`

**document.ready 3**

```
var formData = { 'selectedValue' : $( "#sale_type_2 option:selected" ).val(),
'selectedValue2' : $( "#sale_details_2 option:selected" ).val() };
```

**PHP2**

```
$init_data = $_POST['selectedValue2'];
$init_data2 = $_POST['selectedValue3'];
```

**EDIT**

OP find it, instead of `secondDropdown.text(obj[prop]);` use `secondDropdown.val(obj[prop]);` because he is accessing a textbox.

Comment: Can you run the query on ddbb and add the result you should get?